# How to fix error: "The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened."?

Tags: software-center, software-sources

What does this error message mean?

```
E:Type '‫‪ppa:kiwixteam/ppa‬‬' is not known on line 52 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list, 
E:The list of sources could not be read., 

E:The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be the `ppa` in your `sources`

Try removing it by using the following steps.

1. Use the following command to edit the `sources.list` file:

   `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`
2. Then remove the `‫‪ppa:kiwixteam/ppa‬‬` located at the line `52`
3. Save the file: Press and hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>. While holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> press <kbd>X</kbd>. Let go of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and press <kbd>Y</kbd>
4. Then run the following command to re-synchronize the package index files:

   `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: sorry after   remove the ‫‪ppa:kiwixteam/ppa‬‬ idont what i should doing to save this action

Comment: you can save the file using ctrl + x in the keyboard and after pressing ctrx + x type y it will save the file

Comment: drmohammed@drmohammed-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo apt-get update
E: Type '‫' is not known on line 52 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
drmohammed@drmohammed-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC:~$ 
this is appear , ithink it doesnt work